# Runnable class is not exectued

Tags: java, java-8, supplier

I implemented a virtual counter, just counting up and down between 0-100.

It's very Simple, the factory supplies a VirtualCounter which implements Runnable.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class VirtualTimer implements Runnable {

    private int currentValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 100).findFirst().getAsInt();
    private boolean countingUp;


    private VirtualTimer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (countingUp) {
                if (currentValue == 100) {
                    countingUp = false;
                    currentValue--;
                } else
                    currentValue++;
            } else {
                if (currentValue == 0) {
                    countingUp = true;
                    currentValue++;
                } else
                    currentValue--;
            }
            System.out.println("CurrentValue: " + currentValue);
        }
    }


    public static class CounterFactory {

        public static VirtualTimer getNewCounter() {
            return new VirtualTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

What **works** is this usage of the Runnable

```
  Runnable runnable = VirtualTimer.CounterFactory.getNewCounter();
    Thread test = new Thread(runnable);
    test.start();
```

What **doesn't work** is this:

```
Thread test = new Thread(VirtualTimer.CounterFactory::getNewCounter);
        test.start();
```

So I know how to make this running but tbh I really want to understand why the first attempt works and the second not.

The run method of the second is just never called. Debugger could not help understanding. Any good explanation for this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it why it should work in the first place.

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't be creating `Thread` objects at all anymore, but use an `ExecutorService`(eg `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`) and `submit()` your `Runnable` to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the expression `VirtualTimer.CounterFactory::getNewCounter` 
is of type `Supplier<? extends Runnable>`, not `Runnable`.

Comment: Wow this is what IntelliJ suggested after having this:
 Thread test = new Thread(VirtualTimer.CounterFactory.getNewCounter());
IntelliJ did a false job there. Ty!